# Extension and contraction of ideals in rings of integers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K\subseteq L$ be number fields and let $R \subseteq S$ be the corresponding rings of integers.

**Question.** a) If $I$ and $J$ are integral ideals of $R$ such that $IS \mid JS,$ then $I \mid J.$

b) If $I$ is an integral ideal of $R,$ then $R\cap IS = I.$

c) Characterize the integral ideals $\mathfrak{A}$ of $S$ such that $(\mathfrak{A}\cap R)S=\mathfrak{A}.$

(This is Exercise 9 from Chapter 3 of "Number Fields" by Marcus).

I think I've managed to solve (a) and (b) but would be very grateful if someone could confirm (or refute!) and I'm just a bit stuck on (c)...

---

**Attempted solution.** a) For any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{P}$ of $S,$ we have
$$v_\mathfrak{P}(IS)=v_\mathfrak{p}(I) \times e(\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p})$$
$$v_\mathfrak{P}(JS)=v_\mathfrak{p}(J) \times e(\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p})$$
where $\mathfrak{p}$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R$ below $\mathfrak{P}\;$ (i.e. $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{P}\cap R$).

As such, we have the following chain of implications (in fact, they are equivalences, but whatever):
$$IS\mid JS \; \Rightarrow \; v_\mathfrak{P}(IS) \leq v_\mathfrak{P}(JS) \;\; \forall \mathfrak{P} \; \Rightarrow \; v_\mathfrak{p}(I)\leq v_\mathfrak{p}(J) \;\; \forall\mathfrak{p} \; \Rightarrow \; I\mid J.$$
The second implication uses the fact that every max ideal of $R$ lies below some max ideal of $S.$

b) Let $J=R\cap IS.$ It is clear that $I\subseteq J.$

Moreover, it is clear that $JS=(R\cap IS)S \subseteq IS$ and so, by part (a), we get $J \subseteq I.$

c) I'm not really sure what the author expects here, I mean it's easy to see that
$$(\mathfrak{A}\cap R)S=\mathfrak{A} \; \Leftrightarrow \; \mathfrak{A} = IS \text{ for some integral ideal } I \text { of } R$$
but I don't know what else to say... Any hints?

---

Many thanks!

Comment: How do you know that $\mathfrak A \cap R$ is an integral ideal of $R$? If you do, that would finish $c$, since the other direction is obvious.

Comment: Oops - I should have said “integral ideals” in the question. I’ve edited it now. The reason I’m a bit confused is because isn’t it true that, for *any* extension of commutative rings $R\subseteq S$ and *any* ideal $I$ of $R,$ one has $(R\cap IS)S = IS$?

Comment: Yes, what you say is true , and makes one direction obvious. However, the converse need not be true : if $U$ is an ideal of $S$ such that $(U \cap R)S = U$, then fair enough, we can take $U \cap R = I$ so $U = IS$. But how do we know that $U \cap R$ is integral over $R$? You have to use a theorem for that, don't you? (Something which won't just hold for commutative rings, but requires an integral extension to start with). On a side note, parts a and b are fine.

Comment: By integral ideal of a ring R, I just mean an R-submodule. So I don’t think I require any other properties of the ring extension, no?

Comment: Right, then it seems you are fine! Let me think again and answer if I am sure.

Comment: I  think your answer is fine, so you should write that down yourself and accept it.